# Static vs dynamic website search engine results

Tags: seo, google-search, static-content, dynamic

I am mobile software developer and I want to create a website.

I will have static webpages not dynamic ones (homepage, jobs, about, contact...). When people search on Google with this word: "iphone uygulama yaptirmak", and I want to be on the first page.

Google wants dynamic pages, not static. That's why I want to ask you if it will be a problem for my website?

Answer (score 2):

Google doesn't care about if you use static or dynamic content for your pages because Google bots analyze the final HTML. That's why a full HTML/CSS (without PHP) website can rank very well on Google.

However, Google likes fresh content but dynamic content and fresh content are different things. I encourage you to often add new pages on your website to tell Google your website is alive.

Comment: thank you for answer. I am new on seo and webmaster. I edited question and my english is not very well.

Answer (score 1):

Static pages usually load much faster than dynamic pages - this is a good thing for small sites not able to afford a CDN. PageSpeed is important to Google and you can test your speed at https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/ anything above 80 is considered very good (using browser cache and gzip via *.htaccess* are best for improving speed - [more here)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6724549/caching-and-gzip-compression-by-htaccess).

Make sure your site is mobile friendly (another big ranking factor) and as mentioned above keep your site updated - updating existing pages is also considered as fresh content but new pages are better, once every few weeks is enough. Following other SEO best practices should ensure your rankings for this particular term over time.